# Trim a few characters in the middle of the string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, client-server, trim

I have a client/server program and the client sends [Process ID, Hostname, App Name, File Path] to the server. For now they are sent in one string. I assigned a unique characters for each variable

```
data = "--++" + "  " + "__-_" +processFileName + " " + "--" +processMachinename + " " + ".." + processID + " " + "_--_" + processPath;
```

and the output would be (example below)

```
--++  __-_Client_PC (Running) - Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express --UNICORNV-FA15C8 ..4408 _--_C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress.exe
```

I have tried `Trim` but it will give me an error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
else if (recvDt.Contains("--++"))
{
   string d = "--++";
   recvDt = recvDt.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());
   this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToOutput));

   if (recvDt.Contains("__-_"))
   {
       string fn = "__-_";
       fileName = recvDt.Trim(fn.ToCharArray());
       this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToGrid));
   }
   if (recvDt.Contains("--"))
   {
        string m = "--";
        machineName = recvDt.Trim(m.ToCharArray());
        this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToGrid));

    }
    if (recvDt.Contains(".."))
    {
        string di = "..";
        processID = recvDt.Trim(di.ToCharArray());
        this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToGrid));

    }
    if (recvDt.Contains("_--_"))
    {
        string p = "_--_";
        filePath = recvDt.Trim(p.ToCharArray());
        this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToGrid));

     }

    }
   }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }

}

public void addToGrid()
{
   if (fileName != null && fileName != "" && machineName != null && machineName != "" && processID != null && processID != "" && filePath != null && filePath != "")
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fileName, machineName, processID, filePath);
   fileName = null;
   machineName = null;
   processID = null;
   filePath = null;
}
```

How should I remove those unique characters and display them in the dataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `Remove` instead of `Trim`

so your code should look something like this

```
   if (recvDt.IndexOf("__-_") != -1)
   {
       fileName = recvDt.Remove(recvDt.IndexOf("__-_"));
       this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToGrid));
   }
```

I guess you got the idea

Comment: (recvDt.IndexOf("__-_") != -1) gives an error  of NullReferenceException was unhandled "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: variable `recvDt` seems to be null.
try removing the following lines
   recvDt = recvDt.TrimStart(d.ToCharArray());
   this.Invoke(new rcvData(addToOutput));

Comment: nope... that line is very important.. it receives the whole message

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you are doing all that (insert unique and different strings to separate items) but answering your question in the title

> Trim a few characters in the middle of the string

I'd either use

1. `String.Indexof(string)` to find the index of substring you are searching and creating a new string by removing from that index to the end of the substring
2. `Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement)` to create a new string from the `input` string by replacing the `pattern` with `replacement`

Comment: that is just my way of separating them. do you have any other options to separate them?